# Cauchy integral formula infinitely differentiable without $(-1)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

We have:

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$

$$f'(a) = \frac{-1}{2\pi i}\int_{D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz$$
$$f^{(2)}(a) = \frac{2}{2\pi i}\int_{D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^3}dz$$
$$f^{(3)}(a) = \frac{-3\cdot 2}{2\pi i}\int_{D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^3}dz$$

$$\vdots$$

$$f^{(n)}(a) = (-1)^{n}\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

Why is the part $(-1)^n$ left out if we look at books or lectures. We've done it without that part, but why?

Comment: By the chain rule $$
\frac{d}{{da}}\frac{1}{{z - a}} =  - \frac{1}{{(z - a)^2 }}\frac{d( z- a)}{{da}} =  - \frac{1}{{(z - a)^2 }} \cdot ( - 1) = \frac{1}{{(z - a)^2 }}
$$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it shouldn't be there.

If you differentiate $\frac1{z-a}$ *with respect to* $a$, what you get is $\frac1{(z-a)^2}$, rather than $-\frac1{(z-a)^2}$. So,$$f'(a)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{D(z_0,r)}\frac1{(z-a)^2}\,\mathrm dz.$$And so on…